# Reverse a list while also changing capslock and space

Tags: java

I'm pretty new to java and i am not understanding how i would combine these two things. What i am trying to do is reverse the list while also removing the space and capslock in between the letters and add something at the end to the output. Can you tell me what is wrong with what I am doing? This is to be created using a string builder

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("We need ");

for (int i = tools.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    sb.append(tools[i]);
}
```

this part is gonna reverse the list and

```
for (String s : tools) {
    sb.append(s.toLowerCase().trim() + "s, ");
}
```

this part is gonna lowercase and trim all the non essential stuff. How do I combine these two parts together when Im coding. Really not getting it

so for example if the input is an array of list

String[] tools = {"\tfood", "TABLE", "  car    ", "Phone"};

the output is going to be We need phones, cars, tables, foods and much more.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following the question. Can you please give an example input and the output you'd want for it?

Comment: What character do you think "caps lock" is? That's not a concept in characters. If you just want to remove all spaces and lower-case the string, you can use `text = text.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "")` wherever you need to... (You might want to consider providing a `Locale` to the `toLowerCase` call, too, just to get into good habits.) It's not at all clear why you've got `"s, "` in there though...

Comment: `i.toLowerCase().trim()` just... no.. it's not a String.. it's an integer. Don't do String operations on an integer.

Comment: Please give an example of what is your input and expected output

Comment: Here is a list of items String[] items= {"\tfood", "TABLE", "  car       ", "Phone   "}; I want to return the item in reverse so the output is We need phone, car, table,food and many more things.

Comment: `i.toLowerCase()` ist wrong - you cannot convert an integer to lower case.

Comment: yea my bad i changed that code to 
for (int i = tools.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   sb.append(tools[i]);
  }
 i just forgot to change it

Comment: Correctly state your input and output

Comment: sorry did not see the edit at the bottom of the post. added the input and output expected. thanks

Comment: *removing the space and capslock* makes no sense. capslock is a key on the keyboard it is **not** a character in the string.

Comment: this is a homework assignment. im just following the instruction. this is not a look at what is right or wrong just following instructions.

Comment: Better learn java....String, String array, StringBuilder.....I wish all the best to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("We need ");
StringBuilder sbend = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = tools.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    sb.append(i).append(tools[i]);
    sbend.append(tools[tools.length-i-1].toLowerCase().trim() + "s, ");
}
sb.append(sbend);
```

Just have two stringbuilders. Forget using string functions on integers. integers can't be put to lowercase or trimmed.

For your loop issue you first put your first line items in the first string builder and the reverse part in the second.
then when the loop is finished you join the two.

Comment: The toLowerCase got lost here.

Comment: i dont know i think there is something else wrong as well when i plug in the code shown here. I get something way different. my list is String[] items= {"\tfood", "TABLE", " car ", "Phone "}; and when i do it with michale's method i get We need 3Phone2  car    1TABLE0 food, tables, cars, phones,

Comment: updated the post so u can see the expected input and output expected.

Answer (score 0):

Using StringBuilder and String, it seems to be as simple as below:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("We need ");
String s;
sb.reverse();
s = sb.substring(0).toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s+","");
System.out.println(s);
```

Using only StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("We need ");
StringBuilder sb0 = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = sb.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  sb0.append(sb.substring(i, i+1).toLowerCase().replace(" ", ""));
}
System.out.println(sb0);
```

Comment: can only use stringbuilder

Comment: edited my answer to include StringBuilder only case as well. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the output you are expecting

We need phone, car, table, food

Then maybe you can try something like this-

```
    for (int i = tools.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        sb.append(tools[i].toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
        if (i != 0) {
            sb.append(", ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you show me what i would need to do if i needed to add something like phones, cars, tables, foods. how would i go about getting the last one to show the s without showing the comma after the end. honestly im getting a bit lost as well on your code why did u add the replaceAll("\\s+", "") what does that do. thanks

Comment: Hi,\\s+ is regex expression for one or more whitespace characters so replaceAll("\\s+", "") removes all whitespaces as per your requirement. Also if you need 's' at the end of every item just change sb.append(", ") to  sb.append("s, ") hope that helps

Comment: yea i tried that but at the end of the last one there is gonna be a s, at the end how would i get rid of it would i create an else statement where 
i == (tools.length - 1) {
sb.append("s ");
}

Comment: oh never mind using regex is a no no. only thing we are allowed to use is stringbuilder sadly

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] tools = {"\tfood", "TABLE", " car ", "Phone" };
StringBuilder need = new StringBuilder( "We need " );
String del = "";
for( int i = tools.length - 1; i >= 0; --i ){
    need.append( del );
    need.append( tools[i].trim().toLowerCase() );
    need.append( "s" );
    del = ", ";
}
need.append( " and much more." );
System.out.println( need.toString() );
```

This prints

```
We need phones, cars, tables, foods and much more.
```